# Legendre's Conjecture Theme (Part I)

Tags: reference-request, prime-numbers, analytic-number-theory, conjectures, open-problem

### Main Question

Recently I have been thinking about the [Legendre's Conjecture](https://www.google.co.in/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&source=web&cd=2&cad=rja&uact=8&ved=0ahUKEwiVofubpo7NAhWFNpQKHQdrAAIQFgggMAE&url=http%3A%2F%2Fmathworld.wolfram.com%2FLegendresConjecture.html&usg=AFQjCNEIp6ID7L34_1ypmZyOf2Q-qtp5Vg). I noticed that a proof of the conjecture can be obtained if we can prove any one of the following,

> **Conjecture 1.** For all sufficiently large $n\in\mathbb{N}$ we have, $$\pi\left((n+1)^2\right)+\pi\left(n^2\right)\ne2\pi\left(\dfrac{(n+1)^2+n^2}{2}\right)$$
>
> **Conjecture 2.** If, $$\pi\left((n+1)^2\right)+\pi\left(n^2\right)=2\pi\left(\dfrac{(n+1)^2+n^2}{2}\right)$$then either, $$\pi\left((n+1)^2\right)-\pi\left(\dfrac{(n+1)^2+n^2}{2}\right)>0$$ or, $$\pi\left(\dfrac{(n+1)^2+n^2}{2}\right)-\pi\left(n^2\right)>0$$ for all sufficiently large $n\in\mathbb{N}$.

To me the second conjecture seems more difficult. However, my questions are,

1. Is there a proof of any one of the conjectures stated above? If not, (which is highly probable), can some literature be mentioned which investigates positive integral solutions of any one of the following equations, $$\pi\left(x\right)+\pi\left(y\right)=a\pi\left(\dfrac{x+y}{a}\right)$$or, $$\pi\left((n+1)^2\right)+\pi\left(n^2\right)=a\pi\left(\dfrac{(n+1)^2+n^2}{a}\right)$$ where $a>1$.
2. If the answer of my first question is negative then can anyone give me some hint as to how I should go about proving my any one of the conjectures?
3. Has there been any attempt towards resolving the conjecture by examining the solutions of $$\pi\left((n+1)^2\right)+\pi\left(n^2\right)=2\pi\left(\dfrac{(n+1)^2+n^2}{2}\right)$$

### Remarks (for the sake of completeness)

- As to the question of how one can prove Legendre's Conjecture using any one of the conjectures, we discuss only the proof of Legendre's Conjecture assuming **Conjecture 1** (although admittedly it is trivial). The proof of Legendre's Conjecture assuming **Conjecture 2** is also trivial and not discussed.

  > **Case 1.** Let $$\pi\left((n+1)^2\right)+\pi\left(n^2\right)>2\pi\left(\dfrac{(n+1)^2+n^2}{2}\right)$$In this case observe that since $\pi\left(\dfrac{(n+1)^2+n^2}{2}\right)-\pi\left(n^2\right)\ge 0$, we get that, $$\pi\left((n+1)^2\right)-\pi\left(\dfrac{(n+1)^2+n^2}{2}\right)>0$$and we are done in this case.
  >
  > **Case 2.** Let $$\pi\left((n+1)^2\right)+\pi\left(n^2\right)<2\pi\left(\dfrac{(n+1)^2+n^2}{2}\right)$$In this case observe that since $\pi\left((n+1)^2\right)-\pi\left(\dfrac{(n+1)^2+n^2}{2}\right)\ge 0$,  we get that, $$\pi\left(\dfrac{(n+1)^2+n^2}{2}\right)-\pi\left(n^2\right)> 0$$and we are done in this case.
- In fact using the same argument we can prove the following theorem,

  > **Theorem.** Let $f:D(\subseteq\mathbb{R})\to\mathbb{R}$ be a function such that $f(n)$ is strictly increasing. Then there exists a prime between $f(n)$ and $f(n+1)$ if any one of the following holds,
  >
  > 1. $\pi\left(f(n+1)\right)+\pi\left(f(n)\right)\ne2\pi\left(\dfrac{f(n+1)+f(n)}{2}\right)$ for all sufficiently large $n\in\mathbb{N}$.
  > 2. If $\pi\left(f(n+1)\right)+\pi\left(f(n)\right)=2\pi\left(\dfrac{f(n+1)+f(n)}{2}\right)$ then for all sufficiently large $n\in \mathbb{N}$ we will have either $\pi\left(f(n+1)\right)-\pi\left(\dfrac{f(n+1)+f(n)}{2}\right)>0$ or $\pi\left(\dfrac{f(n+1)+f(n)}{2}\right)-\pi\left(f(n+1)\right)>0$.

### Further Added

A continuation of this question has been asked [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1814231/legendres-conjecture-theme-part-ii) where an alternative conjecture is proposed which would aid us in proving the Legendre's Conjecture even if the conjectures mentioned here doesn't hold in general.

Comment: The expression $\pi((n+1)^2)+\pi(n^2)\neq 2\pi(k)$ for some $k$ with $n^2\leq k \leq (n+1)^2$ works equally well - these observations are not specific to the particular choice you made. More generally, any condition which is true of a function constant on $[n^2,(n+1)^2]$ could be substituted into this post. I would be surprised if such manipulations are used to study the conjecture, since nothing here regards to the distribution of primes so much as to the fact that $\pi$ is non-decreasing.

Comment: @MiloBrandt: See the edit. However, I think that the above approach may be worthy of study because as you noted "since nothing here regards to the distribution of primes so much as to the fact that $π$ is non-decreasing".

Comment: Trying to study solutions of equations of the form $\pi(x) + \pi(y) = a\pi((x+y)/a)$ and such seems impossible to make headway, because of the "$=$" sign.  Usually analytic number theory can deal only with inequalities and estimates.

Comment: @JohnM: In that case we will need to assume that analytic number theory is simply not the right theory for the solution of this type of problems in general.